# "I am most interested in X." vs "I am mostly interested in X."

Tags: phrase-usage

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- "I am most interested in X."
- "I am most*ly* interested in X."

Comment: hope this helps http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/most-the-most-mostly

Comment: **Most** is a superlative, **mostly** is synonymous with **often**. Nice link @Mrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I like all of the pictures,but I am most interested in X

This means that you are more interested in X than you are in any other individual item - A or B or C or ...

> I am mostly interested in X: that's the only picture that I like

This means that the majority of your interest (more than 50% of it) is in X, and your interest in A, B, C... added together is less than 50%.

Most therefore indicates a slight preference for X, whereas mostly indicates that you are not really interested in A,B,C at all.

Most can also be used to mean **very**, though this usage sounds very dated.

> I am most interested in X
>   I am very interested in X

Answer (score 1):

Both words most and mostly have been used as adverbs in the sentences presented.

---

> I am most interested in X.

The sentence conveys two meanings as follows.

1. I am interested in many things, but X is the thing I am interested in 
   more than anything else. It conveys a sense of comparison in the 
   superlative.
2. I am interested in X to a very great extent.

---

> I am mostly interested in X.

It means I am mainly, usually, or almost in entirely interested in X.